# Most efficient way of splitting strings like rubik's cube notations in python?

Tags: python, string, split, rubiks-cube

If a string like `"RL2R'F2LD'"` given,What is the most efficient way of splitting this into Strings `"R" "L2" "R'" "F2" "L" "D'"`?
I'v tried few methods like first splitting them into individual chars and then trying to add them to a list and nothing worked correctly.

Comment: A regular expression would work: `[FBUDLRfbudlrxyz][2']?`

Comment: @minitech can you explain it more please?

Comment: @Madushan: I've updated my answer to explain the regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def rubikstring(s):
    import string
    cumu = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            if cumu: yield cumu
            cumu = ''
        cumu += c
    if cumu: yield cumu
```

could do your job. With

```
>>> for i in rubikstring("RL2R'F2LD'"): i
...
'R'
'L2'
"R'"
'F2'
'L'
"D'"
```

you get your desired result, with

```
>>> list(rubikstring("RL2R'F2LD'"))
['R', 'L2', "R'", 'F2', 'L', "D'"]
```

as well.

Comment: I think this is the answer I'm looking for.re is a good way too but it's not telling me how It work :D

Comment: Note that this solution also will return invalid directions, if there are errors in the rubrik directions (e.g. it'll return `Q33'` just as happily if that's present in the input.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
cubedirs = re.compile(r"[RLFBUDrlfbudxyz][2']?")
cubedirs.findall("RL2R'F2LD'")
```

This outputs `['R', 'L2', "R'", 'F2', 'L', "D'"]`.

The regular expression is actually very simple. The `[..]` character group means: match *one* character from the set given (so an `R`, or an `L`, or an `F`, etc.).

Then we look for a second character group *optionally* matching 1 character, namely a `2` or `'`. The question mark after the second character is what makes it optional; we are specifying that it's also fine if the `'` or the `2` character is not there.

The `.findall()` method simply returns all matches that have been found, so you get a list of all character groups in the input string that match the pattern.

Comment: @minitech: yup, better still.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
[FBUDLRfbudlrxyz][2']?
```

[Here's a live demo.](http://codepad.org/Ze3nP9Dw)

```
import re

s = "RL2R'F2LD'"

for m in re.finditer("[FBUDLRfbudlrxyz][2']?", s):
    print m.group(0)
```

(Sorry for not explaining how to do it in the comments, I don't really know Python.)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, a regular expression would be a good way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{0,1}', "RL2R'F2LD'")
['R', 'L2', 'R', 'F2', 'L', 'D']
```

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous, `{0,1}` can be replaced by `?`, you ignored the `'`.